# PHP DateTime:diff doesn't work from included file

Tags: php, datetime

I have 2 files index.php and functions.php. Functions.php contains all my functions I use in index.php, it works fine expect for one function:

```
function diffSecBetweenDate($dateDebut,$dateFin)
{
    $dateTimeDebut =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y à H\hi',$dateDebut);
    $dateTimeFin =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y à H\hi',$dateFin);
    $dateDifference = $dateTimeDebut->diff($dateTimeFin);

    $seconds = $dateDifference->days * 24 * 60 * 60;
    $seconds += $dateDifference->h *3600;
    $seconds += $dateDifference->i *60;
    $seconds += $dateDifference->s ;
    return $seconds;
}
```

My include:

```
include('include/functions.php');
```

If my function is in index.php it works fine. If my function is in functions.php I got this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in /var/www/acad/include/functions.php on line 235
```

All functions work fine...

Have you any idea?

EDIT 1:

I don't know when PHP crashes but you will find below an extract of my code:

```
$dateReset = '20/03/2012 à 12h00';
$dateNow = new DateTime();
$dateObjectReset = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y à H\hi',$dateReset);
$dateObjectReset->format('d/m/y à H\hi');

$dateNow = $dateNow->format('d/m/y à H\hi');
$dateObjectReset = $dateObjectReset->format('d/m/y à H\hi');

$referenceT = diffSecBetweenDate($dateObjectReset, $dateNow);
```

I use VIM so when I move my function  I do : shit + v => d => ctrl-w => p
So I don't write anything and can't rename something! ^^

Edit 2:

The error was about a different encoding.

Best regards,

Comment: That's very peculiar. Is that _really_ the function you're calling? Can you present a testcase?

Comment: I just created `functions.php` and `index.php` and everything is working fine. Can you check are every path is ok? And name of function, do you call right function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error... The problem was the "à" with a different encoding:

```
createFromFormat('d/m/y à H\hi',$dateDebut)
```

index.php encoding = utf-8
function.php encoding = latin9

If encoding is equal, it works!

Answer (score 0):

the main reason for this is that variable say example `$dateTimeDebut`  is not the `DateTime` Object

it should resemble some thing like

```
$dateTimeDebut= new DateTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

You pass a DateTime to your function and you want to transform it in DateTime. I think that it's your problem. You can just delete the two lines :

```
$dateTimeDebut =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y à H\hi',$dateDebut);
$dateTimeFin =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y à H\hi',$dateFin);
```

And use $dateDebut and $dateFin insted.